# Use female Apple lightning connector for charging LiPo

Tags: connector

I am creating a electronics project powered by a 3.7 V LiPo Battery. I want to make it chargeable via Micro USB or Lightning cables.

Is it possible to buy female Lightning connectors and is it allowed by Apple to use them?

Answer (score 2):

You might find some fancy sellers around the net, but forget to buy something original. To make an Apple product, i.e. that uses Apple parts, you have to be their partner and your device must meet some strict specifications (I swear I've read it somewhere - can't find it anymore).

But hey, no sweat: there's tons of better connectors out there, micro USB is the standard around the world now, and I bet you can rethink your project in order to use something standard instead of something fancy.

Comment: There's also a push by the EU to force manufacturers to adopt a standard charge port, and Micro USB is the current favourite. http://www.engadget.com/2014/03/14/europe-votes-for-common-charger-law/

Comment: I wonder how USB 3.1 Type C will affect this "standard charge port" selection :D